# How to create an sf object which combines geometries to create a set of larger units (e.g., states from counties)

Tags: r, dataframe, geometry, r-sf

I have a shapefile (.shp) where each geographic unit is (the equivalent of) a county. I loaded it and called it `gdfc`. I would like to combine counties to create an `sf` object where each observation is a state. I have tried the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

goems <- map(sort(unique(gdfc[['id_state']])), 
             function(s) st_union(filter(gdfc, id_state == s))) # Dissolving boundaries inside states
gdfs <- data.frame(id_state = sort(unique(gdfc[['id_state']]))) # Data frame with state identifiers
st_geometry(gdfs) <- st_sfc(geoms)                              # Assigning (i.e., attempting to) dissolved geometries
```

However, it did not work, as I got the following error:

*Error in vapply(lst, class, rep(NA_character_, 3)) :
values must be length 3,
but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1*

How should I do to create the set of larger geographic units (states) from the smaller ones (counties)?

Comment: Consider `dplyr::summarize()` on a {sf} data frame. You will find it explained in more detail here https://www.jla-data.net/eng/merging-geometry-of-sf-objects-in-r/

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation; the explanation provided in the link is very good. It worked smoothly.

Comment: and I thank you for your kind words!